# Error with package versions

Tags: versions, iffalse

In a large document of mine I encountered a strange error, which I reduced to this MWE

The environment `NormalText is excluded, so I expect that nothing in it appears in the output. The peculiar thing is, that when it contains an` \iffalse  \fi`AND within that a`\begin{verse} \end{verse}`, the compilation stops with

```
! Extra \fi.
l.24 \end
        {NormalText}
```

After continuing, the output also shows a part of the excluded `NormalText` part.

If I outcomment either the `\iffalse  \fi` or the `\begin{verse} \end{verse}` all seems to be normal.

Is there a bug in package `versions` or in the implementation of the environment `verse`?
Or is it not allowed (then: why not?) to use such constructions?

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{versions}
  \excludeversion{NormalText}
  \includeversion{Remarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{Remarks}
  Text in Remarks
\end{Remarks}
\begin{NormalText}
  Normal Text 1
  \iffalse
  Normal Text 2
  \begin{verse}
    Text in verse
  \end{verse}
  \fi
  Normal Text 3
\end{NormalText}
\end{document}
```

Comment: versions does not seem to have been updated since 2005! A lot have changed since then.

Comment: do not use \iffalse and \fi, even if skipping over text, TeX sees them and that can get very tricky.

Comment: @Jack maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience ?

Comment: @daleif looking at the code I don't think this ever worked

Comment: @Ulrike
I am working on several (non-technical) documents with 250+ pages and about 20 chapters.
I use versions environments like NormalText, Summary, Remarks, Excerpt etc. to select specific pieces of the text. This selection (and more) is done by using GNU make.
NormalText constitutes the larger parts. Herein I sometimes have to outcomment parts that are not relevant anymore, at least at the moment, but I might change my mind about that, so I don't want to delete them. Here I used the iffalse fi construct. But after it bit me, I will use % for commenting out.

Comment: @samcarter
I will check multiaudience. If it allows iffalse  fi constructs (but I'm afraid it will not) I will use it.